# Convexity of the log barrier function

Tags: vector-spaces, summation, logarithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let's consider the following convex optimization problem of minimizing the log barrier function:

$$\min_{\textbf{x}\in \Re^n}f(\textbf{x})=\min_{\textbf{x}\in \Re^n}\bigg\{\textbf{c}^T\textbf{x}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^mlog(b_i-\textbf{a}_i^T\textbf{x})\bigg\}$$

where $x\in \Re^{n\times 1} \text{, } c\in \Re^{n\times 1} \text{, } b\in \Re^{m\times 1} \text{, } A\in \Re^{m\times n} \text{.}$ I am trying to solve this problem for the unconstrained case but first I want to prove that $f$ is in fact convex. What I have thought: the logarithmic function restricts us to $domf=\{x\in \Re^n|b_i-\textbf{a}_i^T\textbf{x}>0\} \text{ for } i=1,2,...,m.$
All of these inequalities define the intersection of $m$ halfspaces which are convex by default and since convexity is closed under intersection, $domf$ is convex.

So for this domain the goal is to prove that the objective function is convex. I guess that since logarithm is concave the minus logarithm is convex and then the non-negative weighted summation preserves convexity. Finally, we add the scalar $\textbf{c}^T\textbf{x}$ which also preserves convexity. But is there a more strict way to prove this?

Comment: You're close. If you're going to be rigorous I think you have to say 1) that $c^Tx$ and $b_i-a_i^Tx$, $i=1,2,\dots, m$, are all *affine* (and, therefore, convex and concave); and 2) that $\log(b_i-a_i^Tx)$ is concave in $x$ because it is the composition of a known concave function and and an affine function of $x$.

Comment: You could, in theory, use a second derivative test here. But I see no reason for it. This is a perfectly reasonable way to prove convexity.

Comment: @mgus: The negative summation is log barrier of linear inequalities. According to Prof. Boyd's book (convex optimization) on page 499. A barrier function is a self-concordant function and a self-concordant function has to be a convex function.